# How to disable the green power light on the Sony Vaio

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio

The Sony Vaio's green power light is extremely bright and very distracting! I can't even look at the screen without this power light being in my view!!

Is there any way to disable it or reduce its intensity? Googling for "sony vaio disable green power light" (and similar combinations) didn't provide anything useful. I tried booting into the BIOS, but it didn't have an option for this. Also, the Viao Command Center didn't have any on it.

I guess sticking a tape over the LED is the only option?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blue LEDs are even worse...

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/07/blue-led-backlash.html
http://texyt.com/bright+blue+leds+annoyance+health+risks

I tried a black sharpie marker with a fine point to "dilute" the brightness of the blue LEDs on my monitor, but it didn't work at all. I think the only option is black plastic (or other, more matching color) matching electrical tape. If you cut it small enough with say an xacto razor knife, it's not too noticeable.

Comment: I've done the same - black electrical tape over the flashing red battery not working light :-).

Answer (score 0):

On some machines I have used a few layers of "scotch" tape to diffuse the light.